# JSON contains incorrect UTF-8 \u00ce\u00b2 instead of Unicode \u03b2, how to fix in Python?

Tags: python, json, string, unicode, utf-8

First note that symbol β (Greek beta) have hex representation in UTF-8: CE B2

I have legacy source code in Python 2.7 that uses json strings:

```
u'{"something":"text \\u00ce\\u00b2 text..."}'
```

I then it calls json.loads(string) or json.loads(string, 'utf-8'), but the result is Unicode string with UTF-8 characters:

```
u'text \xce\xb2 text'
```

What I want is normal Python Unicode (UTF-16?) string:

```
u'text β text'
```

If I call:

```
text = text.decode('unicode_escape')
```

before json.loads, then I got correct Unicode β symbol, but it also breaks json by also replacing all new lines - `\n`

The question is, how to convert only `"\\u00ce\\00b2"` part without affecting other json special characters?

(I am new to Python, and it is not my source code, so I have no idea how this is supposed to work. I suspect that the code only works with ASCII characters)

Comment: Unicode strings in Python are just strings, each character is a single code point. The various UTF endodings don't come inte play until you convert it to bytes (by printing, writing to a file, or converting to `bytes`).

Comment: If you can't just `decode('utf-8')` the erroneous string, I guess you'll need to extract runs of substring where all characters have `ord()` higher than 128, and convert just those, then join the results back together.

Comment: Just for exactness, CE B2 is the UTF-8 representation of the Greek beta ([U+03B2](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3b2/index.htm)).

Comment: Ideally, of course, your JSON input should be correct. I guess there's no chance you can fix the upstream processor, but it bears pointing out that it produces bunk.

Comment: @tripleee - I would be glad if I could decode them in one run, without iterating manually. And yes, I can not fix JSON input.

Comment: @MarisB.: JSON string values are allowed to contain ANY Unicode character as-is OR represent it in **UTF-16** and then encode the individual codeunits in `\uXXXX` format. This is clearly outlined in Section 9 of the [JSON spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf). The JSON you have shown is **malformed**, as encoding **UTF-8** codeunits in `\uXXXX` format is wrong. The *correct* text should have been `u'{"something":"text \\u03B2 text..."}'` instead, or simply `u'{"something":"text β text..."}'`. You should fix the input, not try to work around its errors

Comment: @RemyLebeau - thanks for the info. I would gladly fix the input, if it was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps.  This is limited to 2-byte UTF-8 characters.

```
import re

j = u'{"something":"text \\u00ce\\u00b2 text..."}'

def decodeu (match):
    u = '%c%c' % (int(match.group(1), 16), int(match.group(2), 16))
    return repr(u.decode('utf-8'))[2:8]

j = re.sub(r'\\u00([cd][0-9a-f])\\u00([89ab][0-9a-f])',decodeu, j)

print(j)
```

returns `{"something":"text \u03b2 text..."}` for your sample.  At this point, you can import it as regular JSON and get the final string you want.

```
result = json.loads(j)
```

Comment: I have already managed to implement code, that iterates json structure after loads(), but your code also works, and is more elegant. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a string-fixer that works after loading the JSON.  It handles any length UTF-8-like sequence and ignores escape sequences that don't look like UTF-8 sequences.

Example:

```
import json
import re

def fix(bad):
    return re.sub(ur'[\xc2-\xf4][\x80-\xbf]+',lambda m: m.group(0).encode('latin1').decode('utf8'),bad)

# 2- and 3-byte UTF-8-like sequences and onen correct escape code.
json_text = '''\
{
  "something":"text \\u00ce\\u00b2 text \\u00e4\\u00bd\\u00a0\\u597d..."
}
'''

data = json.loads(json_text)
bad_str = data[u'something']
good_str = fix(bad_str)
print bad_str
print good_str
```

Output:

```
text Î² text ä½ 好...
text β text 你好...
```